# .Net Core T4 Running transformation could not load file or assembly

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, t4

I have a .Net Core Asp.Net MVC app and I am trying to create a T4 file that uses reflection to list all methods of a controller. However, when referencing the Controller class it throws an error. I tried adding the Mvc.Core NuGet package, but the latest version is 2.2.5, and for some reason it's expecting v3.1.0.0.

```
Error       Running transformation: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core, Version=3.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core, Version=3.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating5EB735DC155C701BA88F9010B0EBAB3638F86E339180B5A3766CEE0DDDB7B870EC569C6473D06A892E38A012E5B34C56690737513ADB101F2235F88AEABE2E1D.GeneratedTextTransformation.TransformText()
   at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute1[T0,TRet](CallSite site, T0 arg0)
   at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Object )
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating.TransformationRunner.PerformTransformation()
```

This is my tt file:

```
<#@ template debug="false" hostspecific="false" language="C#" #>
<#@ template language="C#v3.1" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Core" #>
<#@ output extension=".cs" #>
<#@ import namespace="System" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Reflection" #>
class Foo {
    <# Assembly asm = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(UserController)); #>
}
```

Comment: I never figured out the best way to do this, but I ended up finding NSwag as a good solution for creating a list of all the methods in my controller.

Answer (score 0):

You can't refer assembly classes in T4 template directly.
if you want to access the path using assembly of the solution you can use the Host class
`File.ReadAllText(this.Host.ResolvePath("Him.txt"));`

Answer (score 0):

```
<#@ assembly name="$(SolutionDir)YourProject\bin\Debug\Project.Name.dll" #>
```

You can access classes defined in the imported assembly, the tricky thing is to expose internal classes to your T4 template.